# Infinite sum convergence test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to tell if the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n + (-1)^{n+1}}$$
Converges or not. Can i use a comprasion test here? To assume that my sum is bigger than $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n + 1}$? I dont think that's OK, but that's the only way I can think of right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Write out the series:
$$-1(\frac{1}{1 + 1}) + 1(\frac{1}{2-1})-1(\frac{1}{3 + 1})+1(\frac{1}{4-1})-1(\frac{1}{5+1})....$$
$$=\frac{-1}{2} + 1 -\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{8}....$$
Then reorder terms...
$$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}...$$
And it was the alternating harmonic series all along! Which has been proven to equal
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}=ln(2)$$

Comment: Well, i like this one! But I'm new into calculus, so i would also use a version with some classic covergence tests :D Can you explain why does the hint below imply the convergence?

Comment: Since the series is not absolutely convergent, you need to be careful reordering terms.  Here it works, but other times it may not

Comment: Kabo is using Big O notation, which is out of the scope of most 1st and 2nd level Calculus courses. The second part says sequence of partial sums itself approaches 0, which you can think of as the final term in the series is 0, so the last thing you add is nothing, which is a necessary characteristic of a convergent series. I would recommend the ratio or root test, though, which you can read about here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesStrategy.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the information, Henry! What is an instance in which this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_{n+1}-a_n=O(\frac 1 {n^{2}})$. This and the fact that $a_n \to 0$ imply that the series is convergent.

Comment: I agree on that. But could you explain why does it imply the convegence of the series?

Comment: Show that the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence.